# Why can't I get value from radio-button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I'm having troubles getting the value of a set of radio buttons with JQuery. I'm not sure if the problem lies in the .val() function or in the ajax request.
My code for the radio buttons is:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend>New User Signup:</legend>
            <label class="left">Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" size="16"> <br >

            <label class="left">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" size="16"> <br >

            <label class="left">Gender: </label><input type="radio" name="cc" value="M"> Male <input type="radio" name="cc" value="F" checked="checked"> Female <br >

            <label class="left" >Birth Date: </label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="age" size="10" maxlength="10"> <br >

            <input type="submit" id="signup_button" value="Sign Up"> 
</fieldset>
```

while my js code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#signup_button").click(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();
    var gender = $('input[name=CC]:checked').val();
    var birth = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: {
            username: username,
            pass: pass,
            gender: gender,
            birth: birth
        },
        success: function(data)
            {
                window.alert("success");
                $("#register_output").text(data);
            }

    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

In my register.php file I simply do:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$birth_date = $_POST['birth'];

echo "$gender";
```

Comment: `cc` != `CC` ... `$('input[name="cc"]:checked').val();`

Comment: echo "$gender"; should be echo $gender;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case matters:

```
<label class="left">Gender: </label>
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="M"> Male 
    <input type="radio" name="cc" value="F" checked="checked"> Female
```

`cc` != `CC`

```
$('input[name="cc"]:checked').val();
```